# Laravel 5.2 how to redirect to a url with an anchor tag?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I want to redirect to a URL with an anchor tag so that it will automatically open the targetted tab.

i.e redirect to www.test.com/amazing#so-amazing

In my experience, I can only redirect to the route that has my view option. I don't even know how I can attach the # anchor on the redirect option.

This is my return. Currently, I just set it to reload the page.

```
return response()->json([
            'status'      => 'success',
            'redirectUrl' => '',
        ]);
```

Comment: `'redirectUrl' => 'https://www.test.com/amazing#so-amazing'` simple

Comment: If I want to redirect it to a route with the #?

Comment: get the URL from the route helper and concat the `#` part to it .. its strings

Comment: so it woulr be something like route('here')."/#soamazing"?

Comment: should do it :) ... minus the slash

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it out now. You should post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only really need the route URL generated and the hash part of the URL is not dynamic you can just concat some strings together here:

```
'redirectUrl' => route('your.route', [...]) .'#yourhash';
```

Would give you your full URL string you were trying to build.